# jquery .hide function not working from copied example

Tags: jquery, html

I grabbed a script off of w3school and it's working on their example, but when i put it in my html doc, it's not working.

i copied an pasted this into a html file.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_slow

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

using: Mac Safari

Comment: Remember >> http://w3fools.com/

Comment: aww ok, know of any better tutorial sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably loading the file directly with a web browser, which causes the jQuery library not to load from the CDN due to this thing right here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
             ^^
```

Specify a protocol manually:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, jQuery is currently on `1.9.2`. I suggest you switch to that version from the beginning.

Comment: I've changed it to <scr ipt src=" http: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js "></scr ipt> - just without all the spacing... and it's still not working..?

Comment: @LiLiLiu: With all of those spaces?

Comment: oh i used <scr ipt src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></scr ipt> and it worked.. thank you for the recommendation!!